# I am doing a C# project on attendance system, but there is an error while viewing the report

Tags: c#

```
int P=0;
int A=0; 
int L=0;
int E=0;

foreach ( DataRow row in dt_Students.Rows )
{
     P = (int)ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(),"present").Rows[0][6]; // System.InvalidCastException
     A = (int)ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"absent").Rows[0][6];  
     L = (int)ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"late").Rows[0][6];    
     E = (int)ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6]; 
}
```

On the 4th line, I get an error

> System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Using the debugger and/or immediate evaluation, what is `ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6].GetType().Name`? Is it `Int32 (int)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As Olivier Rogier suggested, you need to find out the type of `ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6]`.

`System.InvalidCastException` is thrown when the conversion of an instance of one type to another type is not supported.

If `ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6]` is actually a string, you need to use the methods Nels King suggested.

Until you get the type of what you're trying to cast as int, then we can only make guesses as to what you should to do this

Answer (score -1):

If it's a `string` or a `char`, you can try using `System.Convert.ToInt32(string)`, `int.Parse(string)`, or `int.TryParse(string, out int)`. Unless you tell us the type, unfortunately, we will not be able to solve it.

---

**Edit**: it seems that you just want to use this:

```
int.TryParse(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"present" /* status here */).Rows[0][6], out P /* or A, L, E */)
```

Comment: I tried all these ways but still getting the same error

Comment: @AnuK: What is the type of `.Rows[][]`?

Comment: p = int.Parse((string)(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(), "present").Rows[0][6]));    tried using System.Convert.ToInt32(string) as well,still not working

Comment: What is the type of `.Rows[0][6]`?

Comment: @ Nels King .Rows[][] is of type string

Comment: What is the value of it? If it doesn't contain digits, then no method will work.

Comment: table has attributes studentid,classid,dateatt,status,studentname,classname here this report is used to display the count of present,absent,late and excuse of a particular student in a month

Comment: What is the **value** of `.Rows[0][6]`?

Comment: not sure how to handle those cases

Comment: Assign `.Rows[0][6]` to a string and print it to the output window. Tell me the value.

Comment: .Rows[0][6] is that it is fetching data from the studentsrecordattendance table

Comment: I don't know much about csharp, just did this by seeing a video... Basically while I'm viewing report there are 4 colums like present, absent, late and excuse on selecting the date and subject we should get the number of absentees, present, late and excuse in that month.. So kindly help how to do this

Comment: The three methods I listed should work... if the `.Rows[0][6]` **only** contains digits. If it contains just one letter, none of the methods would work. Sorry

Comment: Wait a minute. You filled up the `int.Parse()` with the string keyword. Incorrect! You should actually pass the `.Rows[0][6]` in there, not the string keyword.

Comment: Can you please send how exactly the code should be here ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6]

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know your project.

Comment: this method is showing some error int.TryParse(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(), "present").Rows[0][6]);   which says no overload for method TryParse takes 1 argument

Comment: System.Convert.ToInt32(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(), "absent").Rows[0][6]); this line shows error saying System.invalidCastException object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Comment: Did you read the signature for `TryParse`? It's `int.TryParse(string, out int /* use P, A, L, or E here*/)`

Comment: Yes I read that but did not know how to modify the code accordingly

Comment: int.TryParse(string, out int (ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6]) ) is this right?

Comment: Nope, it should be `int.TryParse(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month,row[1].ToString(),"execused").Rows[0][6], out E /* or P, A, L, depending on the context */ )`

Comment: p = int.TryParse(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(), "present").Rows[0][6],out p);                                                              // Absence
                A = int.TryParse(ada.GetDataByReport(dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, row[1].ToString(), "absent").Rows[0][6],out A);

    this is displaying an error: cannot convert from object to string

Comment: This is the query i have added in the dataset with FillMethodName as FillByReport and and GetMethodName as GetDataByReport ----SELECT COUNT(Status) AS Expr1
FROM     AttendanceREcordsTBL2
WHERE  (MONTH(DateAtt) = @month) AND (StudentName = @student) AND (Status = @stat)